# How i can create element next to another element

Tags: python, elementtree

```
  <TraitDef>
    <defName>Nudist</defName>
    <commonality>0.7</commonality>
    <degreeDatas>
      <li>
        <label>nudist</label>
        <description>{PAWN_nameDef} enjoys the feeling of freedom that comes from being nude. {PAWN_pronoun} can handle clothing, but will be happier without it.</description>
      </li>
    </degreeDatas>
  </TraitDef>
```

i want to add `<labelFemale>nudist<labelFemale>` next to `<label>nudist</label>`

BUT, that `<label>` can have random parent.
Not only `degreeDatas/li/`
So i'll find `<label>` as

```
    for label in TraitDef.iter('label'):
```

now i can copy  and replace it's tag to 
BUT i can't paste it. By subelement or something. Because i can't find parent.

I think i can find parent as
`TraitDef.findall('.//label...')`

but maybe there is a more rational way?

Comment: You could use lxml which has a `getparent()` method to access the parent. There is also an `addnext()` method to add a following sibling.